# C# File only copies once

Tags: c#

With my filesystemwatcher I check when a file needs to be copied to a 2nd directory. Everytime. So for example I put in test.txt in dir1 and it automatically copies or cuts the file to dir2. Now when I put in test2.txt in dir1, nothing happens. Why is nothing happening the 2nd time?

Edit: It's a **Windows Service**

Here is my code:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    variable_reset();
    cut_copy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"cut"];
    logger("File created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
    filepath = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);
    name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
    extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
    size = e.Name.Length;
    strSelectCmd = "INSERT INTO files (name,size,last_edit,extension) VALUES('" + name + "','" + size + "',now(),'" + extension + "')";
    readquery = "select * from files where name='" + name + "'";
    Mysql();
    postgresql();
    Record();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) == false)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
    {
        copyfolder();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
    }
    else
    {
        if (WaitForFileAvailable(e.FullPath, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
        {
            var file = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);
            var copy_file = Path.Combine(target, e.Name);
            var destination = Path.Combine(target, Path.ChangeExtension(source, Path.GetExtension(source)));

                if ((String.Compare(cut_copy, "cut"))==0)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(file))// Check to see if the file exists. 
                    {                     //If it does delete the file in the target and copy the one from the source to the target.
                        File.Delete(copy_file);
                    }
                    File.Move(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name));
                }
                if ((String.Compare(cut_copy, "copy"))==0)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(file))// Check to see if the file exists. 
                    {                     //If it does delete the file in the target and copy the one from the source to the target.
                        File.Delete(copy_file);

                    }
                    File.Copy(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name));
                }
        }
        else // The file failed to become available within 10 seconds.
        {
            logger("Copy has failed reason: File is being used by another program");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    query = "INSERT INTO files (name,size,last_edit,extension) VALUES('" + name + "','" + size + "',now(),'" + extension + "')";
    Mysql();
}
}
```

Comment: We really don't need to see the entire body of your event handler (`fileSystemWatcher1_Created`) - a simple `MessageBox.Show(...)` would suffice. Perhaps that is the simple example you need to help narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: what is `source`? where do you set it? See code `var file = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's a service...

Comment: Also, you need to show or tell how/where `fileSystemWatcher1` is crated, and the event is wired up.

Comment: what does "nothing happening" mean in this context? does the method not get called? does it give an exception? does it enter the `if` case? does the TV not get turned on?

Comment: @loko Code up a simple example in a Win Forms application, and get the core of it working. You have to learn to narrow down the scope of your issues.

Comment: @Jehof Source is being declared in the appconfig, no worries.